# How to avoid sendmail relay domains spoofing

Tags: domain-name-system, sendmail, spoofing

I have a bunch of domains as `relay domains` at my `sendmail` config, i noticed that some dirty botnet is using dns spoof to be able to send emails using those `relay domains`.

How it works:

a domain **zzz.xxx.tld** resolves back to **127.0.0.1**, when my server tries to resolve zzz.xxx.tld it falls back to 127.0.0.1 *spoof*!

Is there anyway to fix/avoid/block this? relaying only on specific server ips would be better?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Do you need to have a hosts entry pointing to 127.0.0.1? Perhaps you could point the hosts to your external IP instead and only allow relaying from localhost.

Comment: I'm not sure what are the implications of not relaying on 127.0.0.1, some emails are sent by crons and other server internals, not sure if those would be delivered or deferred.

Comment: It mainly depends on the SMTP address they're using, if they're using the external IP or a hostname other than localhost, then that change would break them.